# Karma + AngularJS Multiple expects but only one success

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am new to AngularJS and Karma and trying to follow official AngularJS tutorials. As I am running simple unit testing in Karma, I tried to edit one more test case in the -spec.js file. The `app-spec.js` file is as:

```
'use strict';
describe('PhoneListController', function() {
    beforeEach(module('phonecatApp'));
    it('should create a `phones` model with 3 phones', inject(function($controller) {
        var scope = {};
        var ctrl = $controller('PhoneListController', {$scope: scope});
        expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
        expect(scope.phones.length+2).toBe(5);
    }));
});
```

And here is the sole line in the output:

```
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.013 secs / 0.005 secs)
```

I think I should be expecting two lines or something like `Executed 1 of 2 SUCCESS` and `Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS`.
I do not understand what the problem is. Any idea?

Comment: You only have one it(), theses are the tests. expect are like assertions, you can have multiple ones in a single test.

Comment: Okay, I added one more it() and it gave me `Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS`. How about using only one it() but getting two lines of `Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS`?